# Connection Loss connecting to Azure from Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, azure, vba

I have an application I built using excel VBA - it uses Azure SQL as a database. 
I am able to connect to the database in VBA using provider: SQLOLEDB

```
Example Connection String:
Provider=SQLOLEDB;
Server=tcp:ServerName,1433;
Database=DatabaseName;
Uid=Username@ServerName;
Pwd={Password};
Encrypt=yes;
Connection Timeout=60;
```

Everything works find - I am able to retrieve the data from the database into ADODB recordsets and work with the recordset data in VBA.
After about 10-15 minutes when I try to update the recordset in any way I get the following error:

```
[DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).]General network error. Check your network documentation.
```

This error persists accross different computers using different internet connections using different Azure SQL databases.
I first thought it might be resolved by telling VBA to automatically run a query every 5 minutes (i.e. prevent the connection from being idle for too long) and if the query failed then re connect the ADODB connection. 
I then get a VBA 'Connection Failure' error when I try to update the recordset.

What can I do to fix this issue? 
How can I force the ADODB recordset to stay connected to Azure Database?

Comment: Can you telnet AzuresqlserverIPaddress 1433 from Clients?

Comment: I ran this from powershell - and it returns success:

powershell -Command echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Client.Connect('yourazuresqldatabaseserver.database.windows.net', 1433)) 'success'